# In cocos2dx, I use RenderTexture to capture the screen, but images in scrollview are lost

Tags: ios, scrollview, cocos2d-x, texture2d

After I capture the screen with:

```
auto renderTexture = RenderTexture::create(width, height,Texture2D::PixelFormat::RGBA8888, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES);
Scene* curScene = Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene();
renderTexture->begin();
curScene->visit();
Director::getInstance()->getRenderer()->render();
renderTexture->end();
```

The images and texts in the scrollview which are outside of the screen are lost like this:
1. normal image
[The bottom is outside of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj53q.png)

[the result after capture screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0iEa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The engine would culling the sprite out of screen(at function `Sprite::draw`) to get higher performance. You can either close it by modifying the macro `CC_USE_CULLING`(at file `cocos/base/ccConfig.h`, or you can move the objects in the screen when you capture the screen and move them back after render finish.

Comment: It's useful, Thank you very much